# Calculating Bytes

Tags: byte, bit

> Suppose each pixel in a digital image is represented by a 24-bit color value. How much memory does it take to store an uncompressed image of 2048 pixels by 1024 pixels?

I said for this that 24 bits is 3 bytes. And 2048 Pixels is 6KB (2048 * 3 / 1024) and 1024 Pixels is 3KB (1024 * 3 / 1024). And then I multipled to get 18KB^2.

But the answer says 6MB? How is this possible and how do 1024 and 2048 play into this because the answer says 6MB and doesn't explain.

Comment: 3 Bytes per pixel, 2048 * 1024 pixels, hence we have 2048*1024*3 Bytes. That is exactly 6MB (3 * 2 * 1024 * 1024).

Comment: The fact that you got units of kB^2 ought to be the first clue that something isn't right here.

Comment: @Leon Shouldn't we convert the 2048 into bytes so it would be 3 times it right/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 bit => 24 bit / 8 bit = 3 byte

1) 2048 pixel * 1024 pixel =  2097152 pixel (Area)

1.1) 2097152 pixel * 3 byte = 6291456 byte (Each pixel  3 bytes)

2) 6291456 byte / 1024 byte = 6144 kilobyte

3) 6144 kilobyte / 1024 byte = 6 Megabyte

Comment: I'm confused when you multiply 2048 by 3 and then 2014. Shouldn't we have to multiply both individually and add them?

Comment: Can you use units and explain to me. If you multiply two pixels in step 1 shouldn't it be pixel^2?

Comment: @Asker123 - If I have a 3x3 grid of apples, do I have 9 apples^2?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Great point :D I think I understand now when we measure distances we say square units because we want to quantify each unit. But we can't say that with pixels or apples since they already represent one whole unit in that area. Thanks a lot.